# SQL Server having criteria for subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, having

My query looks like this,

```
SELECT field1, field2, (SELECT TOP 1 field1 from table1) as field3 
FROM table2 
HAVING field3 > 0
```

it throws an error

> invalid column name field3

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that query?

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` in order to be able to use `HAVING`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `HAVING`.  A `WHERE` is more appropriate here.

```
SELECT field1, field2, (SELECT TOP 1 field1 from table1) as field3
FROM table2
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 field1 from table1) > 0
```

Now, I am assuming that you have some work of `WHERE` on the sub query.  That uses values from table2.  Otherwise, pull that query out and assign the value to a variable.

```
DECLARE @field3 AS INT --change this to the correct data type
SELECT TOP 1 @field3 = field1
FROM table1

SELECT field1, field2, @field3 as field3
FROM table2
WHERE @field3 > 0
```

Now, only do this if you need to return empty result set.  If you don't need the empty result set, we can exclude the query all together.

```
DECLARE @field3 AS INT --change this to the correct data type
SELECT TOP 1 @field3 = field1
FROM table1

IF @field3 > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT field1, field2, @field3 as field3
    FROM table2
END
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to use data item aliases within `HAVING` or `WHERE`.

You need to re-call the value within the `HAVING` statement. However, using a `WHERE` clause would be better suited here:

```
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 field1 from table1) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the HAVING to fully define field3 again. ie:

```
SELECT field1, field2, (SELECT TOP 1 field1 from table1) as field3 
FROM table2 
HAVING (SELECT TOP 1 field1 from table1) > 0
```